# "cp" version of "rsync -avuth --delete --progress"?

Tags: bash, rsync, macos-sierra, cp

I searched the forums through, but I feel compelled to ask my question, even if it is slightly redundant.

I use "rsync -avuth --delete --progress" on a regular basis to move files from an SSD raid to multiple drives. The "--delete" function is very important to me as throughout the day I might make changes to files that I've already copied, so I want the newest change on the raid to be reflected on the copies downstream. I run this command a few times an hour.

I'm looking to speed up Rsync. I know everyone asks this. I'm using rsync 3 on OSX Sierra, but CP is *a lot* faster. Rsync tops out at ~190MB/s. A lot of drives I use are faster than 300MB/s.

Can I get the same kind of file treatment from "CP -Ra" (or with something else) as "rsync -avuth --delete --progress"?

- I want to copy files as fast as possible, while maintaining attributes, and only update existing files based on new timestamps.

I feel like I know this is not possible, but it is worth asking.

Thank you

Comment: You might try `--whole-file`, according to the man page it will "copy files whole (without rsync algorithm)", so it might be more like `cp`

Comment: If you does not care about progress, you might want to try cp -au... -a will preserve owner, mode, timestamps, links. And -u will update based on timestamp.

Comment: I suggest to try `--inplace --whole-file`.

Comment: @cyrus - are you referring to  "--inplace --whole-file" for rsync, to speed it up?

Comment: Isn't Rsync limited to a certain speed based off the checksum? Or can rsync achieve faster than 500MB/s speeds?

Comment: @JamieMetzger: yes, to rsync.

Comment: @JamieMetzger: I assume that the calculation of the checksum depends on the speed of the CPU.